# sbt configuration for apache commons

Tags: sbt, apache-commons

There is something wrong with my sbt config.

I entered 
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.1"

into build.sbt, and it complains when I do sbt package.

what is the correct setting to include this lib?

Comment: All should be OK. Check: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-lang3%7C3.3.2%7Cjar

Comment: I guess it needs to be 3.3.2? It builds now.

Comment: I use 3.1 . Sometimes, when somebody uploads file to maven repository - it is unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

Summation of comments and other answers. Steps to check.

- Try and clean and/or rebuild the project
- Make sure that you are including the `libraryDependencies +=` prefix and the correct syntax
- Make sure that the maven repository is included as a resolver
- Make sure that the version you are using actually exist. You can see the latest version [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-lang3%7C3.3.2%7Cjar).

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.3.2"`

Answer (score -1):

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.1".